# Segmentation fault on loader for Sokoban game in C

Tags: c, file

So I'm trying to write a code in C that would create an array of characters from a file looking like :

```
10 8
##########
######  ##
# $  $  ##
# #  .# ##
#  . #.@ #
##$# *   #
##   #####
##########
```

But I'm stuck with a segmentation fault and I've been searching where it could come from unsuccessfully... I would really appreciate if someone could read my code and give me his/her feedback...
Thanks in advance !

```
//We define a structure representing a map (for the Sokoban game)
    typedef struct map map;
    struct map{
        int width;
        int height;
        int x;
        int y;// x and y are the position of the player
        char* p_char; //p_char is pointing an array which will contain the elements of the map, the characters currently on the file above
    };

    //The function that reads the file and store the characters in an array
    char* ReadMap(const char const* filename)
    {
        FILE* p_file = fopen(filename, "r");
        char* p_array = NULL;
        if (p_file = NULL) {
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else{   
            size_t size=1;
            while (getc(p_file)!=EOF) {
                size++;
            }
            p_array=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*size);
            fseek(p_file,0,SEEK_SET);
            for(size_t i=3; i<size-1; i++) {
                p_array[i]=(char)getc(p_file);//i=3 cause we don't want the 2 first int, representing the size of the array
            }
            p_array[size-1]='\0';
            fclose(p_file);
        }
        return p_array;
    }

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        if (argc != 2) {
            fprintf(stderr, "You must provide a file name!\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        //We define a map structure
        map map_loaded; 
        FILE *p_file1 = NULL;
        p_file1=fopen(argv[1],"r");
        if (p_file1==NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot read file %s!\n", argv[1]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        //we're trying to recover width and height, two int at the beginnning of the file
        int width=0;
            map_loaded.width=width;
        int height=0;
            map_loaded.height=height;
        int fscanf_result=0;
            fscanf_result=fscanf(p_file1, "%d %d\n", &width, &height);
        char* p_char=NULL;
        map_loaded.p_char=p_char;
        p_char=ReadMap(argv[1]);
        if (p_char != NULL) {
            printf("%s\n", p_char);
            free(p_char);
        }
    }
```

Comment: if (p_file = NULL)  you are assigning null to p_fill the test should be using == not =

Comment: You leave the three first elements of the data you allocate *uninitialized*. And you still read the dimensions from the first line into the data. And the first line, the one containing the dimensions, will be *five* characters not three (in the example you show) . You need to rethink how you read the contents of the file.

Comment: You set `map_loaded.width = width;` before you have read that data from file, ditto `height`.

Comment: Why aren't you checking fscanf_result?

Comment: 1. Assign `NULL` to the file pointer instead of compareing. 2. `NULL` is treated as false, so the program misunderstand that file read succeeds and try to use the file pointer, which `NULL` is accidently assigned to. 3. `NULL` is passed to file treating functions as file pointer. 4. Ouch!

Answer (score 1):

The cause of Segmentation Fault is the expression `p_file = NULL` used as condition.

`p_file = NULL` is an *assignment* expression. It sets `p_file` to `NULL` and evaluated to the assigned value, which is `NULL`.
`NULL` is treated as false when used as condition.

On the other hand, condition being false indicates file open success when the condition is a *comparison* `p_file == NULL`.

In this case, the condition becomes false when `p_file` is not `NULL`.

For that reason, code that expects that `p_file` is not `NULL` is written
in the `else` clause.

The code includes statements that pass `p_file` to `fgetc()`.

As a result, `NULL` is passed to `fgetc()` and this is one possible reason of Segmentation Fault.

Note that your code still seems wrong after getting rid of this Segmentation Fault.

In the example, the size part is `10 8`, which is 4-character long. This implies skipping "3 characters" doesn't make sense.

Also note that starting `i` from 3 won't skip file contents and just leave first 3 elements of the array uninitialized as Some programmer dude points.

Instead of that, you can "skip the first line". In other words, you can "skip until the first newline character".

```
size_t size=1;
int c;

while (getc(p_file)!=EOF) {
    size++;
}

fseek(p_file,0,SEEK_SET);

while ((c=getc(p_file))!='\n' && c!=EOF) { // drop the first line
    size--;
}

p_array=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*size);

if (p_array!=NULL) { // for in case malloc() fails
    for(size_t i=0; i<size-1; i++) {
        p_array[i]=(char)getc(p_file);
    }

    p_array[size-1]='\0';
}

fclose(p_file);
```

One way to enable `width*i+j` indexing is removing newline characters by adding this code after the line `p_array[i]=(char)getc(p_file);`:

```
if (p_array[i] == '\n') { // if the character is newline, remove it
    i--; // rollback
    size--; // adjust size for the newline character dropped
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the answers ! I've corrected the assignement mistake, it was a simple error of attention... But as you say, I still can't manage to "bypass" the first int of my file, how should i do to begin my loop from the first #...?

Comment: @CandideThovexo I appended it to my answer.

Comment: Thanks really much, didn't know the trick with the while (c=getc(p_file))!='\n'), will take it in note for the next time ! Last question though, i would like to access the element at line i and column j by accessing the element in the array at the index width*i+j, but it seems like it cant be done with the array returned by the function... I've been trying to figure out why the array returned is in 2D but I don't understand... Any idea here ?

Comment: @CandideThovexo The indexing can be realized by removing extra characters. Sample code is added to my answer.

Comment: Thanks very much, works amazing ! Didn't know about the if (p_array[i] == '\n') neither !